# StripeCheckout: Text string must be rendered within a <Text> component

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, stripe-payments

I've been searching google and stackoverflow all day to try to find a solution for this but haven't been able to find an answer. Here is my code. It is saying the error is coming from the StripeCheckout component.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {
  View,
} from "react-native";
import StripeCheckout from "react-stripe-checkout";

function OrderSummary({ route, navigation }) {

  const [product, setProduct] = useState({
    name: "xxx",
    price: 25.45,
    productBy: "xxx",
  });

  const makePayment = (token) => {
    const body = {
      token,
      product,
    };

    const headers = {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    };

    return fetch(`http://localhost:3000/payment`, {
      method: "POST",
      headers,
      body: JSON.stringify(body),
    })
      .then((response) => {
        const { status } = response;
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };

  return (
    <View>
        <StripeCheckout
        stripeKey="my_public_key"
        token={makePayment}
        name="Make payment"
        amount={product.price * 100}
        />
    </View>
  );
}

export default OrderSummary;
```

and here is the call stack

```
Error: Text strings must be rendered within a <Text> component.

This error is located at:
    in span (created by ReactStripeCheckout)
    in button (created by ReactStripeCheckout)
    in ReactStripeCheckout (at OrderSummary.js:40)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at OrderSummary.js:39)
    in OrderSummary (at SceneView.tsx:122)
    in StaticContainer
    in StaticContainer (at SceneView.tsx:115)
    in EnsureSingleNavigator (at SceneView.tsx:114)
    in SceneView (at useDescriptors.tsx:153)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at CardContainer.tsx:245)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at CardContainer.tsx:244)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at CardSheet.tsx:33)
    in ForwardRef(CardSheet) (at Card.tsx:573)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at createAnimatedComponent.js:165)
    in AnimatedComponent (at createAnimatedComponent.js:215)
    in ForwardRef(AnimatedComponentWrapper) (at Card.tsx:555)
    in PanGestureHandler (at GestureHandlerNative.tsx:13)
    in PanGestureHandler (at Card.tsx:549)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at createAnimatedComponent.js:165)
    in AnimatedComponent (at createAnimatedComponent.js:215)
    in ForwardRef(AnimatedComponentWrapper) (at Card.tsx:544)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at Card.tsx:538)
    in Card (at CardContainer.tsx:206)
    in CardContainer (at CardStack.tsx:623)
    in RNSScreen (at createAnimatedComponent.js:165)
    in AnimatedComponent (at createAnimatedComponent.js:215)
    in ForwardRef(AnimatedComponentWrapper) (at src/index.native.tsx:120)
    in Screen (at Screens.tsx:74)
    in MaybeScreen (at CardStack.tsx:616)
    in RNSScreenContainer (at src/index.native.tsx:145)
    in ScreenContainer (at Screens.tsx:50)
    in MaybeScreenContainer (at CardStack.tsx:498)
    in CardStack (at StackView.tsx:462)
    in KeyboardManager (at StackView.tsx:458)
    in RNCSafeAreaProvider (at SafeAreaContext.tsx:76)
    in SafeAreaProvider (at SafeAreaProviderCompat.tsx:42)
    in SafeAreaProviderCompat (at StackView.tsx:455)
    in GestureHandlerRootView (at GestureHandlerRootView.android.tsx:26)
    in GestureHandlerRootView (at StackView.tsx:454)
    in StackView (at createStackNavigator.tsx:87)
    in StackNavigator (at App.js:39)
    in EnsureSingleNavigator (at BaseNavigationContainer.tsx:409)
    in ForwardRef(BaseNavigationContainer) (at NavigationContainer.tsx:39)
    in ThemeProvider (at NavigationContainer.tsx:38)
    in ForwardRef(NavigationContainer) (at App.js:38)
    in App (created by ExpoRoot)
    in ExpoRoot (at renderApplication.js:45)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:106)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:132)
    in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:39)
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\LogBox\LogBox.js:148:8 in registerError
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\LogBox\LogBox.js:59:8 in errorImpl
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\LogBox\LogBox.js:33:4 in console.error
at node_modules\expo\build\environment\react-native-logs.fx.js:27:4 in error
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\ExceptionsManager.js:104:6 in reportException
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\ExceptionsManager.js:171:19 in handleException
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\setUpErrorHandling.js:24:6 in handleError
at node_modules\expo-error-recovery\build\ErrorRecovery.fx.js:12:21 in ErrorUtils.setGlobalHandler$argument_0
at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:63:36 in tryCatch
at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:293:29 in invoke
at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:63:36 in tryCatch
at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:154:27 in invoke
at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:164:18 in PromiseImpl.resolve.then$argument_0
at node_modules\react-native\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:37:13 in tryCallOne
at node_modules\react-native\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:123:24 in setImmediate$argument_0
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:130:14 in _callTimer
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:181:14 in _callImmediatesPass
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:441:30 in callImmediates
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:387:6 in __callImmediates
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:135:6 in __guard$argument_0
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:364:10 in __guard
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:134:4 in flushedQueue
at [native code]:null in flushedQueue
at [native code]:null in invokeCallbackAndReturnFlushedQueue
```

Sorry if this is a duplicate. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Note, this works in my browser, just not on my android phone.

Comment: this error mean StripeCheckout is web package not react pakage, try use web view or search for react pakage

Comment: @AhmedGaber Ah thanks, let me look into that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Ahmed said in comment the checkout plugin used is for react web so it won't work with react-native

I suggest you to look at this plugin [react-native-stripe-checkout-webview](https://github.com/a-tokyo/react-native-stripe-checkout-webview)